# justify-content is not working when div is wrapped in 'flex' parent container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container that has been set 'flex' but I am now trying to pass 'justify-content: space-evenly' to the button container but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```css
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.banner__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.button__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="banner__container">
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button__container">
      <a href="">Yes</a>
      <a href="">No</a>
      <button>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working fine. You just have to set a proper flex value to the child divs of `.banner__container`.

I have done that by setting `flex: 1;` to `.banner__container div`. This will give equal width for each divs inside `.banner__container`

```css
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}

.banner__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.banner__container div {
    flex: 1;
}

.button__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="banner__container">
        <div>
            <p>
                Lorem
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="button__container">
            <a href="">Yes</a>
            <a href="">No</a>
            <button>Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set button__container to `display:inline`.

```css
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.banner__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.button__container {
  display: inline;
  justify-content: space-evenly;  
}
.button__container a, .button__container button {
   margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="banner__container">
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button__container">
      <a href="">Yes</a>
      <a href="">No</a>
      <button>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```